# Problem with whitespace in Bootstrap navbar on small screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, whitespace

I’m helping a friend with her site and everything looks good except for a problem with the nav menu.  When viewed on a phone (or just shrinking your browser window), the navbar height expands and the logo drops down leaving too much white space above it and in the process, stealing it from below.
[image]

Originally, there wasn’t an “ml-auto” on the button class and the hamburger icon was shown on the left side of the screen directly above the logo.  You’d think "navbar-toggler-right" would do the trick, but it doesn’t.  Adding ml-auto pushed the icon to the right, but leaves the white space above the logo.

After extensive testing, it appears that the container div is part of the problem.  If I place the logo outside the container, the problem goes away. However, without it there is no left margin on the logo on larger screens.

How can I remove that white space above the logo, and have the logo and the hamburger show on the same line?  I’m terrible with CSS.

To see it in action, the site is https://italian-getaways.com

Here’s the nav code without the PHP:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white fixed-top mediumnavigation">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbars" aria-controls="navbars" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">navbars
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="container">
    
        <!-- Begin Logo -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href=“/">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </a>
        <!-- End Logo -->
    
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbars">
    
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href=“/info/stories.php">Stories</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
    
            <div class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input id="search-input" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                <span onclick="searchNow()" class="search-icon"><svg class="svgIcon-use"></svg></span>
    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

There’s no special CSS that I can see.  It’s just using Bootstrap 3.13.1.

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just DO one thing which I have discussed below,

```
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right ml-auto collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation">
```

add This Html in Container after logo So it is looks like as you want

[image]

Comment: I can't believe it.  I must have tried everything *but* that.  That's embarrassing.  It works now.  Thank you!